# How to save data on a table using "form_with" method (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a test page listing 3 questions, where a user can input their answers for each of these questions. Then I want their answers to be saved on a table called User_answers table, using "form_with" method.

Q1. What can I do if I want several test pages? I know that usually in the controller, "new" method and "create" method are defined as below, hence have "new.html.erb" where questions are listed.

```
  def new
    @user_answer = UserAnswer.new
  end

  def create
    @user_answer = UserAnswer.create(answer_params)
    if @user_answer.save
      render 'answer'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

If I was to have several test pages, I want the content of create method to be different. (For instance, page "test1" should render page "answer1" when @user_answer is saved, page "test2" should render page "answer2" and so on.)
Do I need to create a new controller for each test pages, or is there a way to assign different create method?

Here is the html for test1. (test2 and test3 both are basically the same, just with different questions.)

```
<%= form_with(model: @user_answer, url: answer_new_path, local: true) do |form| %>
<p>1. <%= Color of apple? %></p>
<%= form.text_field :answer1 %>
<p>2. <%= Color of banana? %></p>
<%= form.text_field :answer2 %>
<p>3. Color of orange? %></p>
<%= form.text_field :answer3 %>
<%= form.submit "Submit!" %>
<% end %>
```

Q2. I can't save my data using form_with.
Below is the structure of my User_answers table.

```
         id: 1
    answer1: red <-- user's answer should be saved in this column
    answer2: yellow <-- user's answer should be saved in this column
    answer3: orange <-- user's answer should be saved in this column
 created_at: 2021-06-11 15:01:32
 updated_at: 2021-06-11 15:01:32
```

This is what I have for homepage/new.html.erb.

```
<%= form_with(model: @user_answer, url: answer_new_path, local: true) do |form| %>
<p>1. <%= Color of apple? %></p>
<%= form.text_field :answer1 %>
<p>2. <%= Color of banana? %></p>
<%= form.text_field :answer2 %>
<p>3. Color of orange? %></p>
<%= form.text_field :answer3 %>
<%= form.submit "Submit!" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my controller.

```
class HomepageController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_answer = UserAnswer.new
  end

  def create
    @user_answer= UserAnswer.create(all_answers)
    if @user_answer.save
      render 'answer'
    else
      render 'test'
    end
  end

  def answer_new
    @answers = all_answers
  end

  private
  def all_answers
    params.permit(:answer1, :answer2, :answer3)
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

The structure of user_answers table;

```
mysql> describe user_answers;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |          
| answer1     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| answer2     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| answer3     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here's my model user_answers.rb.

```
class UserAnswer < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Here's my routes.rb.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/new", to: 'homepage#new'
  get "/answer_new", to: 'homepage#answer_new'
  post "/answer_new", to: 'homepage#answer_new'
end
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but I would suggest consulting the docs about `.create`, `.save`, and `.new` (which you might want to use instead of `.create` for your UserAnswer)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've tried `def create
    @user_answer= UserAnswer.new(all_answers)
    @user_answer.save
  end` but the answers unfortunately still don't get saved...

Comment: can you include the definition of `UserAnswer`? does it include the columns `answer1`,`answer2`, and `answer3`? You're utilising `form_with` with a model, then completely ignoring the model

Comment: I've included the definition of UserAnswer above! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, can you include the section of your `rake routes` that covers the `Homepage` controller? (you might also need to change your "permit" section to be something like: `params.require(:user_answer).permit(:answer1, :answer2, :answer3)` )

Comment: Thank you Jad for your comment. I've added routes.rb at the end. I tried the permit section of the code you suggested, but it still didn't get saved to the table unfortunately...

Comment: You have a rails server running that should display logs and maybe why it is not being saved. Anything in there that could help?